# Using Data from a Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to use two columns from a dictionary in an equation to create a new column. I know I could create np.arrays but I'd rather see if I can do it without doing that.

I'm playing with State Data just to practice.  Here is my code so far:

```
state_data = {
    "name":['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'DC', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Ohio', 'Oklahmoa', 'Oregon', 'Pennslyvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'],
    "pop millions": [4.8, 0.7, 7.0, 3.0, 39.5, 5.6, 3.6, 1.0, 0.7, 21.0, 10.4, 1.4, 1.7, 12.8, 6.7, 3.1, 2.9, 4.4, 4.6, 1.3, 6.1, 6.9, 9.9, 5.6, 3.0, 6.1, 1.1, 1.9, 3.0, 1.3, 9.0, 2.1, 19.8, 10.2, 0.7, 11.6, 3.9, 4.1, 12.8, 1.1, 5.0,0.9, 6.7, 28.3, 3.1, 0.6, 8.5, 7.4, 1.8, 5.8, 0.6],
    "% White":[66, 61, 55, 72, 37, 68, 67, 62, 37, 54, 53, 22, 82, 61, 80, 86, 76, 85, 59, 93, 51, 72, 75, 80, 57, 79, 86, 79, 49, 90, 55, 37, 55, 63, 84, 79, 66, 76, 76, 72, 64, 82, 74, 42, 78, 93, 62, 69, 92, 81, 84],
    '2016 Clinton Vote Share':[35, 38, 45, 34, 62, 47, 55, 53, 93, 48, 46, 62, 28, 55, 38, 42, 36, 32, 38, 48, 61, 61, 47, 47, 40, 38, 36, 34, 48, 48, 55, 48, 59, 47, 28, 44, 29, 52, 48, 55, 41, 32, 35, 43, 28, 62, 50, 54, 27, 47, 23],
    'Homicide Rate per 100k':[8.3, 8.4, 5.9, 8.6, 4.6, 3.9, 2.8, 5.6, 23, 5, 6.7, 2.7, 1.9, 7.8, 6, 3.3, 5.5, 5.9, 12.4, 1.7, 9, 2.5, 5.7, 2, 8.2, 9.8, 3.9, 2.2, 9.1, 1, 3.6, 7.1, 2.8, 5.8, 1.3, 6.1, 6.2, 2.5, 5.8, 1.9, 7.8, 2.9, 7.8, 5, 2.4, 2.2, 5.3, 3.1, 4.7, 3.2, 2.6],
    'Police Shootings 2019':[104, 39, 253, 82, 798, 195, 21, 13, 13, 350, 182, 30, 42, 103, 95, 32, 49, 95, 109, 22, 79, 35, 78, 61, 65, 139, 31, 24, 96, 13, 68, 106, 101, 156, 11, 155, 164, 88, 108, 4, 88, 17, 139, 480, 60, 9, 95, 152, 54, 91, 14]
  }

table = pd.DataFrame(state_data)
print(table)
```

......I want to add a new column police_shootings_per_million that is the 'Police Shootings 2019" divided by "pop millions."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply divide one column into another.

You can define a new column in your `dataframe` like `table['new_column_name'] = something`

You indicated your something to be `Police Shootings 2019 / pop millions`, so set it equal to that.

Why not do `table['police_shootings_per_million'] = table['Police Shootings 2019'] / table['pop millions']`?

Yields:

```
name  ...  police_shootings_per_million
0     Alabama  ...                     21.666667
1      Alaska  ...                     55.714286
2     Arizona  ...                     36.142857
3    Arkansas  ...                     27.333333
4  California  ...                     20.202532
```

Comment: Great, thanks so much.  I was using that formula but instead of "table" I was typing "state_data"

Comment: No problem @NateGo, glad we helped. If this fixed your problem, be sure to mark as correct for others to use!

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
table['police_shootings_per_million'] = table['Police Shootings 2019']/table['pop millions']
print(table)

              name  pop millions  % White  2016 Clinton Vote Share  Homicide Rate per 100k  Police Shootings 2019  police_shootings_per_million
0          Alabama           4.8       66                       35                     8.3                    104                     21.666667
1           Alaska           0.7       61                       38                     8.4                     39                     55.714286
2          Arizona           7.0       55                       45                     5.9                    253                     36.142857
3         Arkansas           3.0       72                       34                     8.6                     82                     27.333333
4       California          39.5       37                       62                     4.6                    798                     20.202532
5         Colorado           5.6       68                       47                     3.9                    195                     34.821429
6      Connecticut           3.6       67                       55                     2.8                     21                      5.833333
7         Delaware           1.0       62                       53                     5.6                     13                     13.000000
8               DC           0.7       37                       93                    23.0                     13                     18.571429
9          Florida          21.0       54                       48                     5.0                    350                     16.666667
10         Georgia          10.4       53                       46                     6.7                    182                     17.500000
11          Hawaii           1.4       22                       62                     2.7                     30                     21.428571
12           Idaho           1.7       82                       28                     1.9                     42                     24.705882
13        Illinois          12.8       61                       55                     7.8                    103                      8.046875
14         Indiana           6.7       80                       38                     6.0                     95                     14.179104
15            Iowa           3.1       86                       42                     3.3                     32                     10.322581
16          Kansas           2.9       76                       36                     5.5                     49                     16.896552
17        Kentucky           4.4       85                       32                     5.9                     95                     21.590909
18       Louisiana           4.6       59                       38                    12.4                    109                     23.695652
19           Maine           1.3       93                       48                     1.7                     22                     16.923077
20        Maryland           6.1       51                       61                     9.0                     79                     12.950820
21   Massachusetts           6.9       72                       61                     2.5                     35                      5.072464
22        Michigan           9.9       75                       47                     5.7                     78                      7.878788
23       Minnesota           5.6       80                       47                     2.0                     61                     10.892857
24     Mississippi           3.0       57                       40                     8.2                     65                     21.666667
25        Missouri           6.1       79                       38                     9.8                    139                     22.786885
26         Montana           1.1       86                       36                     3.9                     31                     28.181818
27        Nebraska           1.9       79                       34                     2.2                     24                     12.631579
28          Nevada           3.0       49                       48                     9.1                     96                     32.000000
29   New Hampshire           1.3       90                       48                     1.0                     13                     10.000000
30      New Jersey           9.0       55                       55                     3.6                     68                      7.555556
31      New Mexico           2.1       37                       48                     7.1                    106                     50.476190
32        New York          19.8       55                       59                     2.8                    101                      5.101010
33  North Carolina          10.2       63                       47                     5.8                    156                     15.294118
34    North Dakota           0.7       84                       28                     1.3                     11                     15.714286
35            Ohio          11.6       79                       44                     6.1                    155                     13.362069
36        Oklahmoa           3.9       66                       29                     6.2                    164                     42.051282
37          Oregon           4.1       76                       52                     2.5                     88                     21.463415
38    Pennslyvania          12.8       76                       48                     5.8                    108                      8.437500
39    Rhode Island           1.1       72                       55                     1.9                      4                      3.636364
40  South Carolina           5.0       64                       41                     7.8                     88                     17.600000
41    South Dakota           0.9       82                       32                     2.9                     17                     18.888889
42       Tennessee           6.7       74                       35                     7.8                    139                     20.746269
43           Texas          28.3       42                       43                     5.0                    480                     16.961131
44            Utah           3.1       78                       28                     2.4                     60                     19.354839
45         Vermont           0.6       93                       62                     2.2                      9                     15.000000
46        Virginia           8.5       62                       50                     5.3                     95                     11.176471
47      Washington           7.4       69                       54                     3.1                    152                     20.540541
48   West Virginia           1.8       92                       27                     4.7                     54                     30.000000
49       Wisconsin           5.8       81                       47                     3.2                     91                     15.689655
50         Wyoming           0.6       84                       23                     2.6                     14                     23.333333
```